# Fixed buffers Nodebo as shape

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer

I want to make different buffers with Nodebo, tool fixed buffers. e.g. 300m 500m from layer a 200 m and 300 m from layer b. etc. When I try to set the file direction, there is only the possibility to select dbf or csv-file. Also when I use 'run as batch process'. The buffer is created but opens as a dbf-table not as a shape. The only way so far seems to be to select each layer single by singel, save buffer by buffer as temp-file and then save as shp. Is there a way I missed?

Comment: Which QGIS version and which platform (Windows, Linux etc) are you using?

Comment: Win 7, QGIS version 2.16.1

Comment: Are you using a model to run this? If so, could you perhaps include some screenshots to show the process and the output options please?

Comment: no, I used the normal qgis tool in nodebo. vector--geoprocessing tolls--fixed distance buffers---run as batch process--- when choosing a layer there must be also selected a direction for the created buffer layer in column "buffer". Here only dbf, xlsx, csv or ods-file format are provided for saving the file

Comment: I can't replicate your issue and I have the same version and platforms you use. What is your input file, is it a shapefile? Try installing the newer QGIS 2.16.2 and see if the problem still persists. If so, perhaps you can upload your file to a public server so that others could test it.

Comment: o.k. this is odd...thank you for your reply. I installed the update 2.16.2 and it is still the same. I puzzled around a bit and found out that this only happens in one special Qgis-Project I work with at the moment. This project is connected to a postgres-database. When I open a new project or another postgres-database connected project the saving is possible also in a lot of different formats incl. shp. ..so it is not solved but I found a way to deal with it...thank you !

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to deal with it :)